# Mavericks Tag colors

Tags: macos, finder-tag

Does anyone know how to make new tags with *custom* colours?

It is clear how to change colours to a predefined set of available colours, but I have no idea how to change to a custom colour. (With the colour picker? Changing templates?)

Answer (score 8):

**You can't.**

The seven colours are unchangeable, because this is needed to provide backwards compatibility with earlier versions of OS X (where they were called labels, you could only have one, and you couldn't change the colour).

If you want a detailed explanation of why tags were implemented this way, and why that restricts the tag colours to the default, then I suggest reading [page 9 of John Siracusa’s Mavericks review](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/10/os-x-10-9/9/).